# ARCore 1.4.1 Align rectangle pararell to floor

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, arcore

How can I set rotation of the placed on vertical plane object to make its bottom side pararell to floor? At the moment vertically placed objects are sticky to the wall but have random rotation. I have been trying to set object on horizontal plane and then adjust vetical objects vector forward to horizontal objects vector up. That seems to work somehow but multiple objects apart of being pararell to each other are rotated in christmas tree shape. Important thing - I want to rotate it relative to real world, not to bottom of the screen.

What I want:

[image: correct setup]

What I get:

[image: Current setup]

```
VerticallyPlacedObject.transform.forward = HorizontallyPlacedObject.transform.up;
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you share a real picture from the problem? Screenshot

Comment: I have already added .